# Relational Database for Arduino on SD card?

Tags: sd-card

I have been searching for some sort of library that can create, query, and insert data into a SQLite style database from an Arduino to an SD card.

I have looked at the Arduino Extended Database library. But I don’t think it will quite fill this role.

I don’t need all the features of sql. But a simple query system would go a long way.

Does anyone know of a library like this?

Comment: RDBMS generally take lots of memory - the Arduino doesn't have lots of memory, so anything you implemented would be horrendously slow. Better is to use a fixed-format binary record based system. Record location = record size * record number.

Comment: can you use wifi to push the data to a "real db"?

Comment: I agree with the two above, if you are looking for a DB on an Arduino you have the wrong hardware solution.  If Wifi is not an option could you use Serial or I2C to connect to a Pi and use the PI as a database server?  Another option might be an ESP32, but I don't know if there are any DB libraries out there for it.

Comment: Alright, no worries. This is good to know. At least I know why this doesn't exist. It's mostly memory constraints. Thanks for the advice!